# root@localhost と root@[IP address]へログインするには？

Tags: mysql

root@localhost と root@[IP address] でログインするにはどうしたらいいですか？

どちらもパスワードが設定されています

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`root@localhost` でログインするには mysqld が動作しているサーバー上で

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

で接続できます。

`root@IPアドレス` でログインするには、そのIPアドレスのクライアントから

```
mysql -h サーバーIPアドレス -u root -p
```

で接続できます。