# mysqliでデータベースに接続するとエラー: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>フォーム画面</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>フォーム画面</h1> 
 
<form action="connect4.php" method="post">
名前を入力：<input type="text" name="yourname">
<input type="submit" value="登録する">
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

で

connect4.php

```php
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'shop');

// 接続状況をチェックします
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("データベースに接続できません:" . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
} else {
    echo "データベースの接続に成功しました。\n";
}
```

で

```
データベースに接続できません:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

となります

Comment: ご質問の内容だけではパスワードが間違っているのではないか、という推測しかできません。コマンドラインから接続した場合うまくつながるでしょうか、また、mysqli_connect_errno()の戻り値が分かれば原因の特定もしやすくなると思います。戻り値をチェックして内容を開示してもらった方がアドバイスが集まりやすいと思います。

Comment: 過去のご自身の質問を参考に、まずアカウントやパスワード設定に誤りが無いかを確認してみてはいかがでしょうか？ - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/71084

Comment: 確認しましたが正しいです

Comment: アカウントやパスワード設定を確認しましたが同じエラーが出ます